# How to run graphql queries from a json file

Tags: android, node.js, kotlin, graphql

I have just started learning about the GraphQl api's in android.The problem which iam facing right now is that, i have no idea about how this api's are working.I have refrences from below link-:

https://www.contentstack.com/docs/guide/contentstack-graphql-api/using-graphql-with-apollo-client-android-sdk

Where it's asking to download schema file of your api.

Is there any way by how i can run my schema.json file in any type of console by which i can understand how this will work to get the correct data.

Thanks

Here is the code below which iam using--

```
    val BASE_URL="https://api.github.com/graphql"

     fun getClient(): ApolloClient {
        val okHttp = OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .addInterceptor({ chain ->
                val original = chain.request()
                val builder = original.newBuilder().method(original.method(),
                    original.body())
                builder.addHeader("Authorization"
                    , "Bearer " + "bac8dc6fd2119fcdbe94332c3e1aa2c43f897b24")
                chain.proceed(builder.build())
            })
            .build()
        return ApolloClient.builder()
            .serverUrl(BASE_URL)
            .okHttpClient(okHttp)
            .build()
    }

}
```

and for calling service...

```
            progress_bar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            client.getClient().query(FindQuery
                .builder()
                .name(repo_name_edittext.text.toString())
                .owner(owner_name_edittext.text.toString())
                .build())
                .enqueue(object : ApolloCall.Callback<FindQuery.Data>() {

                    override fun onFailure(e: ApolloException) {
                        Log.d("exception ",e.message.toString())

                        progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(response: Response<FindQuery.Data>) {
                        Log.d(" " + response.data()?.repository(),"")
                        runOnUiThread {
                            progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                            name_text_view.text = String.format(getString(R.string.name_text),
                                response.data()?.repository()?.name())
                            description_text_view.text = String.format(getString(R.string.description_text),
                                response.data()?.repository()?.description())
                            forks_text_view.text = String.format(getString(R.string.fork_count_text),
                                response.data()?.repository()?.forkCount().toString())
                            url_text_view.text = String.format(getString(R.string.url_count_text),
                                response.data()?.repository()?.url().toString())
                        }
                    }

                })
        }


    }
```

Graphql file used-:

```
  user(login: $login) {
      repositories(first:20){
        nodes{
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Gradle Files

```
implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:1.2.0'
    implementation "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-android-support:1.2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install graphql code generator for android, as In your post I don't see where or do you actually configure a generator. [Tutorial for the code generation setup on android](https://medium.com/the-guild/graphql-codegen-adds-a-new-apollo-android-and-a-new-java-backend-plugins-57832b024e7b).

Just follow the tutorial, if you are not clear with it, you can always checkout angular or react tutorial which uses the same technology, just to get a glimpse of it.

I assume you want a backend on frontend, to have graphql intellisense, typesaftey etc.

Answer (score 0):

To be enabled to consume the API your project must have **schema.json** file that holds mutations, queries and data types of your API. 
So you must download your schema.json file, there are two ways from terminal or android studio itself.

- For downloading schema from your terminal (using the [apollo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo) command-line tools)

  apollo schema:download --endpoint=your_api_url schema.json
- For downloading schema from android studio itself 
  you have to install [JS GraphQL plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8097-js-graphql) to download the scehma.json file

For more information how to setup apollo in your project [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) is the detailed steps